# Optimize Reorganization of Matrix without Loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, optimization, reorganize

**TL;DR**: I am trying to optimize the following short code in Matlab. Because it involves loops over large matrices, it is too slow.

```
for i = 1:sz,
    for j = 1:sz,
        if X(j) == Q(i) && Y(j) == R(i),
            S(i) = Z(j);
            break
        end
    end
end
```

**Specifics**: Basically, I started with three vectors of x, y and z data that I wanted to plot as a surface. I generated a mesh of the x and y data and then made a matrix for the corresponding z values using

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = griddata(x, y, z, X, Y);
```

Because the data is collected in random order, when generating the surface plot the connections are all wrong and the plot looks all triangulated like the following example.[image]

So, to make sure Matlab was connecting the right dots, I then reorganized the X and Y matrices using

```
[R, R_indx] = sort(Y);
[Q, Q_indx] = sort(X, 2);
```

From here I thought it would be a simple problem of reorganizing the matrix Z based on the indices of the sorting for matrix X and Y. But I run into trouble because no matter how I use the indices, I cannot produce the correct matrix. For example, I tried

```
S = Z(R_indx); % to match the rearrangement of Y
S = S(Q_indx); % to match the rearrangement of X
```

and I got this barcode...[image]

Running the first block of code gives me the "desired" result pictured here. However, this takes far too long as it is a double loop over a very large matrix.[image]

**Question**: How can I optimize this rearrangement of the matrix Z without for loops?

Comment: I suspect there is no need to arrange your data......attach your data and shows us your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the following solutions, and test both with your matrices. Do they perform faster? The *array indexing* solution does, what you asked for, i.e. the re-arrangement of the matrices. The *vector indexing* might be even better, since it sorts your original vectors instead of the matrices, and generates the output directly from there.

```matlab
% Parameters.
dim = 4;

% Test input.
x = [2, -2, 5, 4];
y = [1, -4, 6, -2];
z = rand(dim);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = griddata(x, y, z, X, Y);
[R, R_indx] = sort(Y);
[Q, Q_indx] = sort(X, 2);

% Initialize output.
S = zeros(dim);

% Provided solution using loop.
for i = 1:numel(z)
  for j = 1:numel(z)
    if (X(j) == Q(i) && Y(j) == R(i))
      S(i) = Z(j);
      break
    end
  end
end

% Output.
S

% Solution using array indexing; output.
S_array = reshape(((X(:) == Q(:).') & (Y(:) == R(:).')).' * Z(:), dim, dim)

% Solution using vector indexing; output.
[r, r_indx] = sort(y);
[q, q_indx] = sort(x);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(q, r);
Z = griddata(q, r, z, X, Y);
idx = (ones(dim, 1) * ((q_indx - 1) * dim) + r_indx.' * ones(1, dim));
S_vector = Z(idx)
```

Example output:

```matlab
S = 
   0.371424   0.744220   0.777214   0.778058
   0.580353   0.686495   0.356647   0.577780
   0.436699   0.217288   0.883900   0.800133
   0.594355   0.405309   0.544806   0.085540

S_array =
   0.371424   0.744220   0.777214   0.778058
   0.580353   0.686495   0.356647   0.577780
   0.436699   0.217288   0.883900   0.800133
   0.594355   0.405309   0.544806   0.085540

S_vector =
   0.371424   0.744220   0.777214   0.778058
   0.580353   0.686495   0.356647   0.577780
   0.436699   0.217288   0.883900   0.800133
   0.594355   0.405309   0.544806   0.085540
```

Comment: I couldn't get your array indexing solution to work, but the vector indexing works like a charm. Thanks a bunch for your help!